# JSON -> Xcode stringformat

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xcode, json

I use this method to access my mysql database from Xcode:

> NSString *URL = [NSString
>   stringWithFormat:@"http://test.test:8888/test/loadUserData.php?username=%@",
>   userName];
>
> NSString *rawJSON = [[NSString alloc]
>   initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL
>   URLWithString:URL]];
>
> const char *convert = [rawJSON
>   UTF8String]; NSString *responseString
>   = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:convert];
>
> if ([rawJSON length] == 0) {
>       [rawJSON release];
>
> }
>
> SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser
>   alloc] init];
>
> userInfo = [[parser
>   objectWithString:responseString
>   error:nil] copy]; SSN = [userInfo
>   objectAtIndex:0];
>
> [parser release];
>
> return userInfo;

Everything works great. EXCEPT that I can't compare strings in the result with normal nsstrings. If I say

if ([userinfo objectAtIndex:0) == @"Dan")
{
..do something
}

Xcode never sees that it is the same value..
I don't know if there is something wrong with the format (My database is UTF-8)
And how can I convert the result so xCode can compare the response with NSStrings?

Thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` does not compare the value of strings, it just compares their addresses.

Use

```
if ([[userinfo objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Dan"]) { ... }
```

or something similar instead.

Comment: One way to think of it is as - object comparison; your original code was asking, "Is object A equal to object B?". So, instead think, "Are the contents of object A the same as the contents of object B?" Don't forget @"A String" is not actually a string literal it's shorthand for an instance of NSString with contents 'A String'; i.e. an object in it's own right.

Comment: @user753126 Yes, == compares the pointers/addresses. The variables you throw at == *are* pointers, i.e. NSString *. So for comparison you always want something like isEqualXXX etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you know for sure that you have string data on both sides of the condition you could use

```
if ([userinfo objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Dan") {
    // summat...
}
```